# tf.feature_column.input_layer returning wrong shape of tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I use `tf.feature_column.input_layer`, it seems to be returning a tensor with shape `[number of features, batch size]` when it should be returning the opposite - `[batch size, number of features]`. The code is:

```
## Generate the input functions
def create_train_input_fn(x_train, y_train): 
    return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x=x_train,
        y=y_train, 
        batch_size=32,
        num_epochs=500,
        shuffle=True)
p = create_train_input_fn(df, df.reward_next)

## Create the custom estimator
deep_q = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=deep_q_model_test,
    params={
        'feature_columns_current_state': feature_columns_results['current'],
        'feature_columns_next_state': feature_columns_results['next'],
        'gamma': GAMMA,
        'n_classes':ACTION_DIM,
        'hidden_units':[256, 256],
        'batch_size':32
    })

# Train the Model.
deep_q.train(p)
```

The documentation clearly states

> Its shape is (batch_size, first_layer_dimension)

I am using my own custom estimator function (`deep_q_model_test` in the code above), and within that I have the first line as:

```
net = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, feature_columns)
print('shape of input to forward pass: ' + str(net.get_shape()))
```

And the shape shown in my print (and also after inspecting the tensor board) is:

```
shape of input to forward pass: (?, 32)
shape of hidden layer: (?, 256)
shape of hidden layer: (?, 256)
```

I am using the prebuilt pandas input function as well to be fed into it: tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn. The feature columns were built with it being:

```
[_NumericColumn(key='cpc', shape=(1,), default_value=None, 
dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 _NumericColumn(key='comp_win', shape=(1,), default_value=None, 
dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 _NumericColumn(key='impressions', shape=(1,), default_value=None, 
dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 _NumericColumn(key='clicks', shape=(1,), default_value=None, 
dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 _NumericColumn(key='cost', shape=(1,), default_value=None, 
dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 _NumericColumn(key='transactions', shape=(1,), default_value=None, 
dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 _NumericColumn(key='cpo', shape=(1,), default_value=None, 
dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 _NumericColumn(key='reward', shape=(1,), default_value=None, 
dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 _IndicatorColumn(categorical_column=_IdentityCategoricalColumn(key='hrs', 
num_buckets=24, default_value=None))]
```

Also the neural net is actually trains and inspecting the tensorboard it does show the shape is flipped. The problem with this is when I run a batch size which is different, lets say for prediction where i want to only predict 1 observation, it wont work.

**EDITED**
Adding in the actual code for the model

```
def deep_q_model(features, labels, mode, params):
"""deep q learning model"""

## Create the models/
def nn1_forward(features, feature_columns, hidden_units, n_classes):
    net = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, feature_columns)
    print('shape of input to forward pass: ' + str(net.get_shape()))

    # Hidden layers (batch size, hidden_nodes_dim)
    layer_number = 0
    for units in hidden_units:
        net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=units,
                              activation=tf.nn.relu,
                             name='layer' + str(layer_number),
                             reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
        print('shape of hidden layer: ' + str(net.get_shape()))
        layer_number += 1

    # Logits layer with no activation (batch size, output dims)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(net, n_classes,
                             activation=None,
                            name='layerOutput',
                            reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
    print('shape of output layer: ' + str(logits.get_shape()))

    return logits

## Current state forward pass
logits_current = nn1_forward(features,
                            params['feature_columns_current_state'],
                            params['hidden_units'],
                            params['n_classes'])
tf.summary.histogram('logits_current', logits_current)

# Reshape the action tensor
action_num = tf.reshape(tf.cast(features['action_num'], tf.int32), [params['batch_size'], 1])
# Generate a counter
counter = tf.reshape(tf.range(params['batch_size']), [params['batch_size'], 1])
actions = tf.concat([counter,
                     action_num], axis=1)
print('shape of actions ' + str(actions.get_shape()))

# Get the Q values based on the actual action taken for each observation - flatten to (batch size, 1)
predicted_q_values = tf.transpose(tf.gather_nd(logits_current, [actions]))
print('shape of predicted q values: ' + str(predicted_q_values.get_shape()))


## next state forward pass
logits_next = nn1_forward(features,
                          params['feature_columns_next_state'],
                        params['hidden_units'],
                        params['n_classes'])
tf.summary.histogram('logits_next', logits_next)

# Get the maximum Q value possible for each observation - flatten to (batch size, 1)
max_next_q_values = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_max(logits_next, axis=1), [params['batch_size'], 1])
print('shape of max q values: ' + str(max_next_q_values.get_shape()))


### Bellman equation
# Rewards is what was fed in as "labels"
rewards = tf.cast(tf.reshape(labels,  [params['batch_size'], 1]), tf.float64)
expected_q_values = tf.add(rewards,tf.multiply(tf.cast(params['gamma'], tf.float64),
                                               tf.cast(max_next_q_values, tf.float64)))
tf.summary.histogram('expected_q_values', expected_q_values)
print('shape of expected q value: '+ str(expected_q_values.get_shape()))

## Compute predictions - predictions will calculate the Q values without activation
predicted_classes = tf.argmax(logits_current, 1)
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    predictions = {
        'class_ids': predicted_classes[:, tf.newaxis],
        'probabilities': tf.nn.softmax(logits_current),
        'logits': logits_current,
    }
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)


# Compute loss
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=tf.cast(expected_q_values, tf.float32),
                                    predictions=tf.cast(predicted_q_values, tf.float32))


# Compute evaluation metrics.
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=loss)

# Create training op.
assert mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
```

Comment: Can post the code of deep_q_model_test ?

Comment: @NipunWijerathne sure will add that in, its actually trying to implement deep q learning with the bellman equation

Answer (score 0):

Okay stupid me - there was actually no issue. It happened that my batch size was exactly the same as the number of features I had, so I got confused and assumed the shape was wrong!